# Changing jest directory structure

Tags: javascript, jestjs

It appears that the default with jest.js is to mix tests in the same directory as the code using naming conventions so that, e.g., browserify will skip the testing code when packing up everything for actual use.

But what I want is to be able to organize my code something along the lines of

```
src
+-main
  +-js
  test
  +-js
```

I thought that doing something like

```
"jest": {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src/main/js/",
    "<rootDir>/src/test/js/"
  ]
}
```

in `package.json` would do the trick but I still get a file not found error with

```
const columnizer = require('columnizer.js');
```

any ideas on how to make this work?